# Hadoop: is it possible to put several files in one split?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have input which consists of many files. Their size is larger than blockSize. Each file, after being processed, induces at least one InputSplit to process it.

A question is: is it possible to process many files in one split?

Basing on FileInputFormat code it is not:

```
    for (FileStatus file: files) {
337      Path path = file.getPath();
338      long length = file.getLen();
339      if (length != 0) {
340        BlockLocation[] blkLocations;
341        if (file instanceof LocatedFileStatus) {
342          blkLocations = ((LocatedFileStatus) file).getBlockLocations();
343        } else {
344          FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(job.getConfiguration());
345          blkLocations = fs.getFileBlockLocations(file, 0, length);
346        }
347        if (isSplitable(job, path)) {
348          long blockSize = file.getBlockSize();
349          long splitSize = computeSplitSize(blockSize, minSize, maxSize);
350
351          long bytesRemaining = length;
352          while (((double) bytesRemaining)/splitSize > SPLIT_SLOP) {
353            int blkIndex = getBlockIndex(blkLocations, length-bytesRemaining);
354            splits.add(makeSplit(path, length-bytesRemaining, splitSize,
355                                     blkLocations[blkIndex].getHosts()));
356            bytesRemaining -= splitSize;
357          }
```

So, probably, we should use another InputFormat or create our own. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process several big files in one split doesn´t make sense in Hadoop, where the goal is compute data in parallel by different splits at the same time instead to process them sequential using the same container. But if still you want to procees big files in one split, you could use **CombineTextInputFormat** and set a big enough value to **mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize** property. The normal use of CombineTextInputFormat is to process several small files by the same container. Here there is an example of it use: https://github.com/lalosam/HadoopInExamples/blob/master/src/main/java/rojosam/hadoop/CombinedInputWordCount/DriverCIPWC.java

Comment: RojoSam, thanks a lot! Thats what I was looking for. I cannot process my files in parallel as their number is significantly bigger than number of nodes.

Comment: That shouldn´t matter. If you require more containers than available "slots", Hadoop should orchestrates it. That is what hadoop does. At the end it will be sequential but if in a future you can add more nodes then hadoop will take advantage for it in automatic.

Comment: The hadoop resource manager (YARN) will instantiate containers and execute map/reduce (or other type) task as soon as there is enough resources available for it. Keeping the remaining tasks in a queue.

Comment: Got it, thanks! But this will introduce additional overhead for container creation, temp folders creation/removal etc. If processing is sequential anyway  - may be its really better to use that CombinedInputSplit?

Comment: The problem with process more than one HDFS block by the same task is that they could be in a diffetent node and it wll be required to transfer them to the node where the task is running. The "splitter" try to avoid this situation as possible without warranty. And the things could go very wrong with especulative tasks and with tasks retries on failures, where you need to move your task to a different node where very probably you don't have all the same blocks together requiring to transfer them.

Comment: Ok, but whats the difference with sequential container creation?  Again,    each file occupies one block and it may reside on any node, so each Container may try to fetch it via network.

Comment: Imagin that in the DataNode A you have the block 1 of file F1 (F1-1) and the block 1 of file F2 (F2-1). Then the job decided to combine both blocks in the same task (a mapper). The process will run local in DataNode A in a sequence (as you want). But if the task start to take more time than other tasks hadoop will launch a "speculative tasks" in other DataNode to process both blocks F1-1 and F2-1. What is the probability that a replica for both blocks are in the same node and it be free ? Not very probably, Isn´t it ? Then the scheduler will assign the task ...

Comment: to a DataNode that have at least one the the two blocks (if it is possible) and then it will start transferring the other block from other DataNode with the replica. In this situation you will start spending more time transferring files between nodes than the overhead of instantiate a new container. Maybe some seconds to intantiate a new container vs some minutes to transfer a big file. A similar situation will happen if a task fail.

Comment: So finally I see 2 potential issues with CombineTextInputFormat  approach. 1) chances that all small files to be processed by one CombineTextInputFormat  container reside on one node are very low. network overhead. for sequential containers - each may run on the node where file resides (but if some node is idle and file is not there - it will copy it anyway). 2) if  CombineTextInputFormat  job fails all files should be reprocessed, while in a singleContainerPerFile approach only one re-run requiered. Is my understanding correct?